# boost::bind with image_msg

Tags: boost, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to write code to take two image messages called /stereocam/left/image_raw, and /stereocam/right/image_raw, each from two different cameras. I want to combine them to both into one image, however I can't figure out how to set up one callback function to determine which camera the particular image came from. I tried this, but it won't compile.

image_transport::Subscriber sub1 = it.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image> ("/stereocam/left/image_raw", 1, boost::bind(imageCallback, _1, 1));
image_transport::Subscriber sub2 = it.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image> ("/stereocam/right/image_raw", 1, boost::bind(imageCallback, _1,2));

and

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg, int queue_id)
{
}

I tried a variation of this using just ROS instead of image_transport and it compiles just fine, but this doesn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33824/boost::bind-with-image_msg/) by [Fred99](https://answers.ros.org/users/1423/fred99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-05-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-05-12**:
Offhand, it's sensor_msgs::Image, with a capital I. Can you post your complete code, or at least the smallest snippet that doesn't compile?

**Comment by [Fred99](https://answers.ros.org/users/1423/fred99/) on 2012-05-12**:
image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image>("/stereocam/left/image_raw", 1, boost::bind(imageCallback, _1, 1));

That is the part that it says doesn't have a matching function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to remove the template parameter for the subscribe call. According to the [image_transport api docs](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/image_transport/html/classimage__transport_1_1ImageTransport.html#a1c847a2c719c874f84a78a6a60b98c7f), the version of it.subscribe that accepts a `boost::function` object for the callback is not templated.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fred99](https://answers.ros.org/users/1423/fred99/) on 2012-05-12**:
Thank you! It compiles now. Much appreciated :)

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-12**:
Please use the checkmark to mark this answer as "accepted" if it solved your issue. That way, the next person to have this problem can easily find the solution. Thanks for helping to keep ROS Answers organized and easy to use!